# Send and Receive CompositeByteBuf in Netty

Tags: java, netty

For my application, i want to be able to send and receive CompositeByteBuf.
I am using `MessageToMessageEncoder<CompositeByteBuf>`, but while i can 
successfully send (waiting to write through `channelFuture.sync()` and then checking `channelFuture.isDone()` that it is true), on the receiver side I'm getting nothing.
I must be missing something. Also, another related question, what would be the
most efficient way to send CompositeByteBuf that contain components that are 
extra large? For instance direct ByteBufs of maximum size. Right now it fails for very small buffers (testing), but eventually this will be used with large direct off-heap buffers.

The following is my Encoding part:

```
pipeline.addLast("snappy encoder", new SnappyFrameEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("frameEncoder", new LengthFieldPrepender(8));
pipeline.addLast("bytesEncoder", new MessageToMessageEncoder<CompositeByteBuf>() {
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, CompositeByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        out.add(msg);
    }
});
```

And the decoding part:

```
pipeline.addLast("snappy decoder", new SnappyFrameDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(
      IGraphConstants.NETTY_MAX_FRAME_SIZE, 0, 8, 0, 8));   
pipeline.addLast("bytesDecoder", new MessageToMessageDecoder<CompositeByteBuf>() {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, CompositeByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        msg.retain();
        out.add(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking from the pipeline, I don't see a reason it will not work.  Could you insert the LoggingHandler to the beginning of the pipeline of the receiver so that you can check the actual traffic?

Comment: Hi trustin, I used the LoggingHandler and the message was actually received (number of bytes), but the decode function wasn't triggered for some reason, maybe it is expecting ByteBuf. I ended up writing my own ByteToMessageDecoder, which is suited better for my scenario.